# How do I sort for entries that don't have a certain value that I'm looking for?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a google sheet [contact book] w/ 21 columns x 7631 rows.
I have a designated row for "Company Profile" to assign an entry to just the company & not the employees so I can sort the data w/o the individual ppl.
Not all companies have this designated row since I started doing this recently. I want to find the companies that don't have this designated row & add the entry.

What's the best way to do this w/o manually checking through all 7631 rows?

Comment: best way is to share a copy of your sheet with example sample of your desired output

Answer (score 0):

I think my best self-solution is to query a copy of the data set & sort for the companies that do have it, then UNSELECT those from a filtered view of the data set & add them in.